# Weblogic managed server state and health is not updating

Tags: weblogic, jmx, weblogic-10.x

I have implemented SSL in one of my managed server (WLS) on port 7003. Status/health update is stopped after SSL implementation. Server is running but state is always showing as SHUTDOWN. I am not able to find what settings needs to check for JMX connectivity.
Please help[image]

Answer (score 0):

if this is listening on port 7003, why the console is showing port 9010?

Comment: 9010 is Listen port and 7003 is SSL listen port. This is the issue as the screen  is not updating with latest data.